# how to upgrade glx version from 1.2 to 1.3 or higher on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, opengl, mesa, octave

I am now running octave for some plots, but it would always return an empty window.

Octave is now running on WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 with xming for image forwarding, and it returns the following warning message:

> WARNING: Application calling GLX 1.3 function "glXCreatePbuffer" when GLX 1.3 is not supported!  This is an application bug!

I checked the openGL version:

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Intel(R) HD Graphics 520
OpenGL version string: 1.2 (4.5.0 - Build 24.20.100.6299)
OpenGL extensions:
```

but when checking mesa version, I only got:

```
$ glxinfo | grep Mesa
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
```

I also tried to install Mesa 20.3 manually, but it doesn't change anything

The other way I tried was to use xorg-edgers repository, but it doesn't support Ubuntu 20.04 yet.

How can I upgrade glx from 1.2 to 1.3 or higher to properly run octave?

Thanks